# Flagging a suspicious bounty

Tags: discussion, flags, bounty

I was in the process of raising a moderator intervention flag on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40921173/get-meaningful-iowinresponse-contentlength) question, when I thought I would raise my concern here first.

Something about this post does not feel on the up and up. It differs from normal behavior with new members. Now I could be completely off base here or paranoid but it looks like someone is trying to transfer reputation to a new account.

Is it worth flagging the post if it smells fishy?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

What bounty?

In all seriousness, if you see suspicious behavior around a bounty, feel free to use a custom flag to let us know why something feels really off. In this case, that would be the fact that a new account posted two answers within two minutes to the same person's questions, got one of those accepted, and then two minutes later a bounty was offered on the answered question.

If we find evidence that the bounties were indeed an attempt at setting up puppets or laundering reputation between friends, we'll step in and invalidate the bounty (as well as warning the people involved). If we don't, we'll generally still mark these flags as helpful if they did indeed look odd.

Comment: Yeah I watched as you stepped in and remedied the situation. The second answer came as I was writing up the this post. The whole thing just felt off. I'll go with my gut next time and just raise the flag.