# Adding 'start bounty' option to the mobile app

Tags: feature-request

I tried opening a bounty via the mobile app and just couldn't seem to find the option.

**Note:** The post was eligible for a bounty and I started it a few minutes later from the website.

Comment: Mobile app, is that still alive? Just use the webversion.

Comment: Unofficially, the apps are abandoned. You won't see SO publicly say that though.

Comment: Just remembered that there actually *was* a mobile app for SO after seeing this post.

Comment: The whole bounty system should get phased out in the first place. It doesn't really blend in with the rest of the rep system. There's for example nothing stopping me from inviting my buddy to SO, then dump 1.5k bounty on his first answer. Boom, lots of moderating previligies without knowing a thing about how the site works.

Comment: @Lundin If you don't abuse the system, it has pretty positive sides. I do agree it has its downsides, one of it being your reputation is lost even if you received no answer.

Comment: @Lundin I would think that would be caught and that both the reputation sender and recipient [would be reprimanded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339037/691711).